# No cursor for writing visible on hover

Tags: html, css

I display a label on an input field and I'd like to show a cursor for writing on the label hover. What would be the easiest solution for it? I don't want to use a placeholder label. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cotfry8k/

Snippet:

```css
label {
    left: 50px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: text;
}

label:hover span {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<form>
<label><span>Name</span></label>
  <input type="text"/>
</form>
```

Comment: as a side-note consider using `placeholder="name"` attribute of the input

Comment: thanks, but as I mentioned in the question, I didn't want to use it this time.

Comment: oh my, i didn't see it xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `cursor: text;` style on `label`.

```css
label {
    left: 50px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: text;
}

label:hover span {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label><span>Name</span></label>
  <input type="text"/>
</form>
```